# R: Naming matrix rows/columns in a for-loop works in console, but not when knitting

Tags: r

I am attempting to use a `for` loop to rename the rows and columns of a matrix via the following code:

```
Z = matrix(c(1:120), 15, 8)
for (i in 1:15) {
  rownames(Z)[i] = paste0("[", format((-1)*(4-(i/10)), nsmall=1), "]")
}
for (j in 1:8) {
  colnames(Z)[j] = paste0("[", (j-1)/100, "]")
}
```

This works as expected when entered into the console, and produces the following matrix `Z`:

```
       [.00] [.01] [.02] [.03] [.04] [.05] [.06] [.07]
[-3.9]     1    16    31    46    61    76    91   106
[-3.8]     2    17    32    47    62    77    92   107
[-3.7]     3    18    33    48    63    78    93   108
[-3.6]     4    19    34    49    64    79    94   109
[-3.5]     5    20    35    50    65    80    95   110
[-3.4]     6    21    36    51    66    81    96   111
[-3.3]     7    22    37    52    67    82    97   112
[-3.2]     8    23    38    53    68    83    98   113
[-3.1]     9    24    39    54    69    84    99   114
[-3.0]    10    25    40    55    70    85   100   115
[-2.9]    11    26    41    56    71    86   101   116
[-2.8]    12    27    42    57    72    87   102   117
[-2.7]    13    28    43    58    73    88   103   118
[-2.6]    14    29    44    59    74    89   104   119
[-2.5]    15    30    45    60    75    90   105   120
```

However, I need to include this in an R Markdown document that knits to PDF, as in this MWE:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "1970-01-01"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
Z = matrix(c(1:120), 15, 8)
for (i in 1:15) {
  rownames(Z)[i] = paste0("[", format((-1)*(4-(i/10)), nsmall=1), "]")
}
for (j in 1:8) {
  colnames(Z)[j] = paste0("[", (j-1)/100, "]")
}
```
````

When trying to knit this document, R Markdown returns the error

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

and the execution halts.

I found that the above error has been extensively discussed, but that the cause of the error is when attempting to supply too few or too many names for the number of rows or columns. However, that should not be the case here, and since the code does not return this error when entered into the console, I have been unable to find a cause for Markdown rejecting it.

*(I realize that assigning vectors to the row and column names is preferred, especially since the names are known; but this is for a university class assignment which is intended to familiarize me with loops, and so the assignment requires that everything must be done inside loops.)*

I am using R version 3.6.2 and RStudio version 1.2.5033 on Windows 10 version 1909 build 18363.1082. Any help is appreciated!

Edit 1: Output of `sessionInfo()` as requested by @Wil:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.2  htmltools_0.4.0 tools_3.6.2     yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.3     
 [6] rmarkdown_2.0   knitr_1.26      digest_0.6.23   xfun_0.12       rlang_0.4.4    
[11] evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: I get the sae `Error in dimnames(x)` error when I try to load your starting example code (defining Z and row/colnames).  Before I try and knit anything.  Try clearing your environment - it looks like the problem is upstream from knitting.

Comment: Can you add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question?

Comment: @andrew_reece I cleared my environment and now the error occurs at the console as you indicate. What could that mean? Prior to clearing the environment I was able to modify the loop code to change the names to anything.

Comment: @Shaman see my answer below, a for loop is not going to work with the approach you're using.

Comment: @Wil I've added the output to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a matrix `Z` without any defined row or column names, the value of `rownames(Z)` and `colnames(Z)` is `NULL`.  You're getting this error because you're trying to subset `[i]` into `NULL`, which doesn't work.

```r
Z = matrix(c(1:120), 15, 8)
rownames(Z) # NULL
rownames(Z)[1] # NULL 
rownames(Z)[1] <- "foo" 
# Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Note that this is discussed in the base R documentation for [`colnames()`/`rownames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html):

> constructions such as
>
> `rownames(x)[3] <- "c"`
>
> may not work unless x already has dimnames, since this will create a length-3 value from the NULL value of rownames(x).

You *can* assign rownames with a vectorized input, such as:

```r
rownames(Z) <- paste0("[", format((-1)*(4-(1:15/10)), nsmall=1), "]")
```

But from your post it sounds like this exercise is focused on `for`-loops.  Per the docs, this isn't a viable option for setting names on a new matrix.

If you can't use a purely vectorized approach, the closest solution involving a `for`-loop that I can think of is to loop the rowname values into a vector, then assign the vector as `rownames(Z)`.  But this seems like a needless middle step, so I'm not sure it's really a useful pattern to learn.

```r
new_rownames <- vector(mode = "character", length = nrow(Z))

for (i in 1:15) {
  new_rownames[i] = paste0("[", format((-1)*(4-(i/10)), nsmall=1), "]")
}

rownames(Z) <- new_rownames
```

Another option might be to assign an empty set of values to rownames/colnames for `Z`:

```r
Z = matrix(c(1:120), 15, 8, dimnames = list(1:15, 1:8))
```

Then you could use your original loops as intended.

Comment: I found that I was able to work around the error by assigning the names once, i.e. `rownames(Z) = c(1:15)`, after which loops will work,and Markdown will knit properly. How do I go about posting my solution to my own question? Sorry, I am a new user!

Comment: @Shaman note that I just made an update which essentially provides your solution.  You wrote in your original post that vector assignment was not allowed at all, which is why the approach `rownames(Z) = 1:15` seemed off-limits, as it is vector assignment.  But if that's acceptable for your homework, then what I've mentioned in my answer covers this approach.

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance! My apologies for poorly communicating the requirements; this will be acceptable on the assignment.